# Open Android App through QRCode generated from a Deep link and using Camera App

Tags: android

Is it possible to open our app with the camera app by reading a QRCode generated with a deep link?

I have the `AndroidManifest.xml` configured to open a custom scheme and I am able to open a specific screen with the deep link URI.

Lets say: `myapp://test/path/to/screen` is working as intended.

I have the following `intent-filter`

```
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="test" android:path="path/to/screen" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I am able to do the following:

- Open my app with a launch from other apps :check:
- Open my app through a button link in a website :check:

What I am not able and I am trying to do is:

- Open my app through the default android camera, reading the QRCode generated with the URI `myapp://test/path/to/screen`.

The camera always asks to open in one of the browsers and not my app. Is there a way to at least our app be listed as one of the options to open the deep link?

Comment: Have you tried using [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/#android-app-links)?

Comment: I can't use web links for my use case. I need to use a custom scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question since meanwhile, I found the "issue".

After Android 12 the stock camera of the OS will open the custom schemes as URLs and not as deeplinks.

You have the following options:

- Implement a QRCode reader on your own app
- Use a different QRCode reader app
- Don't use custom schemes but App Links, as [Trent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11882081) mentioned in his [comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77217468/9636).